# combinator pattern, java Function <e, t>

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-interface

```
public interface CustomerRegVali extends Function<Customer, ValidationResult>

static CustomerRegVali isEmailValid(){
    return customer -> customer.getEmail().contains("@") ?
            SUCCESS : EMAIL_NOT_VALID;
}

static CustomerRegVali isDobValid(){
    return customer -> Period.between(customer.getDob(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() > 16 ?
            SUCCESS : NOT_ADULT;
}
static CustomerRegVali isPhoneValid(){
    return customer -> customer.getPhone().startsWith("+0") ?
            SUCCESS : PHONE_NOT_VALID;
}

default CustomerRegVali and(CustomerRegVali other){
    return customer -> {
        ValidationResult result = CustomerRegVali.this.apply(customer);
        return result.equals(SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
    };
}


@Main method
    ValidationResult result = isEmailValid()
            .and(isPhoneValid())
            .and(isDobValid())
            .apply(customer);
```

Right so.. Looking back at an old uni project for functional java, I stumbled upon this combinator. Am I clueless or does .apply not get called twice on the primitives? Seems rather redundant.

Comment: What leads you to believe it's being called twice? There are two calls to `apply` in `and`, but they apply to different objects.

Comment: I'm not strong in functional java, but during .and(isPhoneValid), is .this not referring to isEmailValid - and .other to isPhoneValid. With this in mind, next iteration would then be .this referring to isPhoneValid on which we will call .apply once again.

Comment: It's referring to the composite `CustomerRegVali` we've made so far, which will eventually delegate down to a single call to `.apply` on the original validator. All of the `and` calls are just building a computation, and the final `apply` collapses the whole thing and calls the built-up pieces.

Comment: "delegate down to a single to .apply on the original validator". Does this mean that none of the primitives' apply get's called as we chain through the Main call? I don't see how a virtual method entailing all .apply logic is called at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> ... during .and(isPhoneValid), is .this not referring to isEmailValid - and .other to isPhoneValid. With this in mind, next iteration would then be .this referring to isPhoneValid on which we will call .apply once again.

I think you're confusing `this` with `CustomerRegVali.this`, which is different. You might be imagining that you're building a structure that looks like this:

[image]

but in fact it looks like this:

[image]

Within a call to `apply`, `this` points to one of these boxes, but as you can see, there's never a case in which `this` points to `isEmailValid` while a separate `other` link points to `isPhoneValid`.

In the implementation of `apply` for `and`, you're not calling apply on `this` but rather on the captured value `CustomerRegVali.this`, which is the validator on which you invoked `and`.

In setting up the validator, you:

- Call `isEmailValid`.
- Invoke `and` on the `isEmailValid` validator, passing the `isPhoneValid` validator. This creates a new `and` validator that retains a reference to the `isEmailValid` validator and `other`.
- Finally invoke `and` on the result of the first `and`, passing a new `isDobValid` validator, building a new `and` validator just like the previous one.

That process produces the structure in the second diagram.

So there are five validators in total, and you call `apply` once on each.

Comment: Not necessarily the best answer in here. Personally though, I loved the visualization.

Comment: Great answer @WillisBlackburn, very well documented and presented.

Answer (score 1):

Please, be aware that you are building a chain of functions and the result of the chain is a function as well.

As @SilvioMayolo pointed out too, when you perform `apply` on the chain this function in turn will invoke, in the order you indicated, if the validation result is `SUCCESS` and the chain could proceed, the different, individual, `CustomerRegVali` `apply` methods.

In order to understand this behavior, consider the following interface definition.

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface CustomerRegVali extends Function<Customer, ValidationResult> {

    static CustomerRegVali isEmailValid(){
      return customer -> {
        System.out.println("isEmailValid called");
        return customer.getEmail().contains("@") ?
            SUCCESS : EMAIL_NOT_VALID;
      };
    }

    static CustomerRegVali isDobValid(){
      return customer -> {
        System.out.println("isDobValid called");
        return Period.between(customer.getDob(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() > 16 ?
            SUCCESS : NOT_ADULT;
      };
    }
    static CustomerRegVali isPhoneValid(){
      return customer -> {
        System.out.println("isPhoneValid called");
        return customer.getPhone().startsWith("+0") ?
            SUCCESS : PHONE_NOT_VALID;
      };
    }

    default CustomerRegVali and(CustomerRegVali other){
      return customer -> {
        System.out.println("and called");
        ValidationResult result = CustomerRegVali.this.apply(customer);
        return result.equals(SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
      };
    }
}
```

And this simple test case:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
  Customer customer = new Customer();
  customer.setEmail("email@company.org");
  customer.setDob(LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1));
  customer.setPhone("+000000000");

  final CustomerRegVali chain = isEmailValid()
      .and(isPhoneValid())
      .and(isDobValid());

  System.out.println("valid result:");

  ValidationResult result = chain.apply(customer);

  System.out.println(result);

  customer.setPhone("+900000000");

  System.out.println("\ninvalid result:");
  System.out.println(chain.apply(customer));
}
```

This will output:

```
valid result:
and called
and called
isEmailValid called
isPhoneValid called
isDobValid called
SUCCESS

invalid result:
and called
and called
isEmailValid called
isPhoneValid called
PHONE_NOT_VALID
```

As you can see, as a consequence of the function chaining and the way you programmed these functions, the individual `apply` methods will be called when you invoke the final chain's `apply` method in the order specified and only if the chain should proceed because the validation result is `SUCCESS`.

Precisely, assuming your code:

```kotlin
@Main method
    ValidationResult result = isEmailValid()
            .and(isPhoneValid())
            .and(isDobValid())
            .apply(customer);
```

- When you invoke `apply` you are invoking the second `and` function.
- According to the implementation provided for the `and` function, this will in turn invoke the `apply` method of the function in which the second `and` is defined. In this case, it implies that the `apply` method of the first defined `and` function will be invoked.
- In turn, again according to the implementation provided for the `and` function, the `apply` method of the function in which the first `and` function is defined will be invoked, which happens to be `isEmailValid` now.
- `isEmailValid` is invoked. If it returns `SUCCESS` then, according to the logic implemented in the `and` function - we are moving forward now, from the first validator to the last one - it will invoke the next validator function in the chain, the one provided as argument of the first `and` function, `isPhoneValid`, in this case.
- `isPhoneValid` is invoked. If it returns `SUCCESS` then, according to the logic implemented in the `and` function, again it will invoke the next validator function in the chain, the one passed as argument of the second `and` function this time, `isDobValid` in this case.
- `isDobValid` is invoked. The process would continue like this if new validators exist.

Closely related, some time ago I came across [this wonderful article](https://www.pgrs.net/2015/04/23/partial-function-application-in-java-8/) about functional programming and `partial` functions. I think it can be of help.

Comment: Very thorough. Definitely appreciate the time taken. Personally I had to award another answer, solely based on the included visualization. Including test cases, is very nice as well though.

Comment: You are welcome @RasmusHjorthLüdeking. I agree with you, honesty the response from Willis is wonderful, specially for the visualization. Thank you very much in any way. I am happy to hear that the responses were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The three `isXyzValid` values are of type `CustomerRegVali`, meaning that they're functions that take a `Customer` as an argument and return a `ValidationResult`.

The `and` function is a combinator that combines two validation functions into one. I.e. it returns a function that takes a customer as an argument and returns a ValidationResult according to whether the two validation functions succeed when applied to the given customer. It has a short-circuit so that if the first validation function fails then the second isn't called - the combined function simply returns the failed validation result returned by the first function.

The `and` combinator is defined in the example code as a non-static method of the `CustomerRegValin type. It could have been defined as a standalone static method, in which case it would take two function arguments (i.e.` CustomerRegVali` values) and would look like this:

```
CustomerRegVali and(CustomerRegVali thiz, CustomerRegVali other) {
    return customer -> {
        ValidationResult result = thiz.apply(customer);
        return result.equals(SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
    };
```

It should be clear here that apply is called for each function argument once (at most).

To use this method you would have to call it like this:

```
CustomerRegVali isEmailandDobValid = and(isEmailValid(), isDobValid());
```

If you wanted to chain another function using `and`, then it would look like this:

```
CustomerRegVali isEmailandDobAndPhoneValid = and(and(isEmailValid(), isDobValid()), isPhoneValid());
```

It's evidently not that readable. We could improve this if we could use `and` as an infix operator, e.g.:

```
isEmailValid() and isDobValid() and isPhoneValid()
```

Unfortunately Java doesn't support user-defined infix functions, however we can get fairly close by changing `and` to be a non-static method on CustomerRegVali - this then allows us to write the above expression like this:

```
isEmailValid().and(isDobValid()).and(isPhoneValid())
```

To do this we need to change our `and` definition so that it is a non-static method and also remove this first argument (as that function argument will now be the object on which we're calling the `and` method). As a first attempt we might think this would work:

```
CustomerRegVali and(CustomerRegVali other) {
    return customer -> {
        ValidationResult result = this.apply(customer);
        return result.equals(SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
    };
```

however this will fail to compile. The problem is that inside of the lambda expression (the body of the function inside the inner pair of braces), `this` refers to the immediate enclosing scope - the lambda itself and not to the outer `CustomerRegVali` object. To fix this we need to disambigute `this` by prefixing it with `CustomerRegVali.`:

```
CustomerRegVali and(CustomerRegVali other) {
    return customer -> {
        ValidationResult result = CustomerRegVali.this.apply(customer);
        return result.equals(SUCCESS) ? other.apply(customer) : result;
    };
```

This now matches the definition provided in the example. We can use this `and` method to chain 3 validation functions together:

```
CustomerRegVali isEmailandDobAndPhoneValid =
        isEmailValid().and(isDobValid()).and(isPhoneValid())
```

and if we want to apply the function to an actual customer object then we need to call the `apply` method:

```
ValidationResult result =
        isEmailValid()
                .and(isDobValid())
                .and(isPhoneValid())
                .apply(customer);
```

I hope it is now clear that each validation function is only called once (at most) in this example.